powershell 5.1, load specific assembly version for the current instance only
I want to use MimeKit but the server on which I want to run the script is far from up-to-date regarding the assembly dependencies. And no, I can not update the assembly system wide due to frozen configuration.
What I did is, put all the .dll, .xml of MimeKit, its dependencies, and the dependencies' dependencies, in a folder, then Add-Type -Path '<path to mimekit.dll>'
Doing so, MimeKit works fine. My questions are:

is this the right way to make PowerShell use specific assembly version?
once auto-loaded that way, will these assembly version affect only this instance of PowerShell and won't mess with other instances (remember, frozen configuration)?

edit 1
I found that I can also store the .dll in different folders and load them using
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse $AssemblyRoot\*.dll).fullname | %{ [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($_) }

It tried to load them using multiple Add-Type but it seems that I need to add them in the right order, the innermost first.

is this method better than the auto-load one above?
and the most important question remains: will these assembly version affect only this instance of PowerShell and won't mess with other instances (remember, frozen configuration)?

